# difference between ref.watch(myProvider.state) and ref.watch(myProvider).state

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm watching a provider's state in another provider.

This is my StateProvider.

```
final counterProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);
```

Now there are two ways to watch this.

```
final isEvenProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) {
  final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider); // First
  return (counter.state % 2 == 0);
});
```

```
final isEvenProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) {
  final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider.state); // Second
  return (counter % 2 == 0);
});
```

What is the difference between the two?
When should we use which?

Comment: if you use stateProvider the return value will always be the state. So in my opinion the first one is the correct one, though the second one may be correct

Comment: @DanielAidoo This confuses me more .

Comment: use the first one when using stateProvider then the 2nd one when using statenotifierprovider